# How to get UTC duration using moment?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I wanted to get the duration in UTC, which is stored in database. But while I will try to get the duration, it will give me +timezone value.

```
var duration = moment.duration('17:43:00');
```

It will display 23:13 in my application. But I want 17:43

Comment: *"I wanted to get the duration in UTC"* That makes no sense. Durations have no timezone.

Comment: I need to convert this for my bootstrap time picker. So, while I am trying to display using above, It will displays 23: 13 in my time picker.

Comment: Durations have nothing to do with timepickers. I suggest reading up: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: So, Please suggest me how I will create a valid date object with '17:43:00' this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by doing below:

```
var time = '17:43:00';
var timeSplit = time.split(':');
var startTime = moment().hour(timeSplit[0]).minute(timeSplit[1]).second(timeSplit[2]);
```

So, above code will give me the correct date object for my time picker from string of time received from my database.

Thanks